# Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. Property 'children' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I want to create the navbar by using react-bootstrap
I put the code as below in src\components\header.tsx which want to make header as component :

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="bg-body-tertiary">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>                 
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>                  
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

but it return the error
on navbar.brand or container

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Property 'children' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(207, 9): 'children' is declared here.
index.d.ts(1466, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>, "ref"> & { ...; }, BsPrefixProps<...> & NavbarProps> & BsPrefixProps<...> & NavbarProps & { ...; }'
```

can I know what's wrong inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem. Just add `esModuleInterop` to `tsconfig.json` file or if exists, turn on this property as follows:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "esnext",
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "sourceMap": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
    },
    "include": ["src"]
  }
```

According to official typescript documentation

> By default (with `esModuleInterop` false or not set) TypeScript treats `CommonJS/AMD/UMD` modules similar to ES6 modules.

It's highly recommended to enable this option if you're working with third-party libraries that use `CommonJS` or AMD modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to make sure your react and react-dom libraries and types libraries are up to date.

`yarn upgrade --latest react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom`

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can update your @types/react, I had same error, but after update @types/react to last version, error go away, my currect version 18.2.64
[example error](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/7514)